# Unable to run under Jetty from Eclipse: Unknown scope: debug

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

While trying to run my application with "Run with Jetty" runner

[image]

I am getting an error

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyProject".
Unknown scope: debug
```

Project is maven-bases, made with webapp archetype.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regular jetty user. Just now installed Jetty 8.1.14 from eclipse marketplace on my Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 (Mac) and it is working like a charm.  Please try to upgrade eclipse/jetty if you are using older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the Run Jetty Run eclipse plugin rather than the "Run With Jetty" plugin.